# SQL JOIN + WHERE

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, join

**Background that you'll need to know:**
I have two tables - one called 'userprofiles', one called 'comments' - there is a lookup field called 'CommentUser' in the 'comments' table which links to a field in 'userprofiles' called 'TravellerName'.

The user's avatar image path (which is /Account/UserProfileAvatar/[TravellerName].jpg) is found in the 'userprofiles' table under a field called 'UserAvatar'.

The gridview itself uses a TemplateField with an asp:Image using Eval and then the Database field. It is my intention that the comments section displays these 4 fields of data:

1. the user's avatar
2. the username ('CommentUser')
3. tagline
4. comment body

I am fine for points 2 - 4 but point 1 is where you guys come in.

The client side code looks like so:

> ```
> <%-- Comments Box --%>
>  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
>     DataSourceID="CommentsDataSource" Height="167px" Width="325px">
>     <Columns>
>       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
>         <ItemTemplate>
>         <div style="background-color:Silver">
>         <div class="avatar-frame">
>         <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UserAvatar") %>'/>
>         </div>
>         <h1><%# Eval("TagLine")%></h1>
>         <h2><%# Eval("CommentUser")%></h2>
>         <p><%# Eval("CommentBody")%></p>
>         </div>
>         </ItemTemplate>
>         <AlternatingItemTemplate>
>         <div style="background-color:White">
>         <div class="avatar-frame">
>        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UserAvatar") %>'/>
>         </div>
>         <h1><%# Eval("TagLine")%></h1>
>         <h2><%# Eval("CommentUser")%></h2>
>         <p><%# Eval("CommentBody")%></p>
>         </div>
>         </AlternatingItemTemplate>
>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>     </Columns>
>
> </asp:GridView>
>
> <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CommentsDataSource" runat="server" 
>     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookMeetConnString %>" 
>     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookMeetConnString.ProviderName %>" 
>     SelectCommand="SELECT comments.CommentUser, comments.TagLine, comments.CommentBody, comments.BookID, userprofiles.TravellerName,
>   userprofiles.AvatarURL FROM userprofiles INNER JOIN comments ON
>   userprofiles.[TravellerName] = comments.[CommentUser] WHERE ([BookID]= ?)">
>     <SelectParameters>
>         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="ID" />
>     </SelectParameters>
> </asp:SqlDataSource>
> <%-- End of Comments Box --%>
> ```

As you can see, I've made a bit of a hash up of the query (I had a rough idea that I needed to do a JOIN but I know absolutely nothing about JOINs in SQL).

The logical construct of my query will be like this:

1. SELECT comments.CommentUser, comments.TagLine, comments.CommentBody **(these are the text fields needed in the comments table)**
2. Retrieve the UserAvatar from 'userprofiles' for each user that has commented
3. Display only the comments for that particular bookid (final part of the SQL query will be **WHERE ([BookID] = ?)**

I hope you understand what the query that I am envisioning?

**EDIT:** Datatype of 'BookID' is an *access lookup* (created through the lookup wizard). All tables have been created through Microsoft Access. In terms of the actual datatype of the field, to my knowledge Access automatically assigns 'number' datatype to all lookups. The lookup query itself is from'BookID' in the table 'comments' to 'ID' in the 'booklist' table.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) can help you.

Comment: Are you getting an error? you should mention the table name to which 'BookId' columns belong to.
.. WHERE (TableName.[BookID]= ?)

Comment: It would be easier for us to understand the question if you post the snapshots of your tables

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ASP.Net syntax but it seems that there is some confusion in the data you are actually pulling.

This is your SQL query:

```
  SELECT comments.CommentUser,
         comments.TagLine,
         comments.CommentBody,
         comments.BookID,
         userprofiles.TravellerName,
         userprofiles.AvatarURL
  FROM   userprofiles
         INNER JOIN comments
           ON userprofiles.[TravellerName] = comments.[CommentUser]
  WHERE  ([BookID] = ?)
```

Yet, to fetch the avatar URL, you use:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("UserAvatar") %>
```

and not:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("AvatarURL") %>
```

So, which is it? `UserAvatar` or `AvatarURL` ?

Comment: It is AvatarURL, UserAvatar was a separate field in the 'comments' table which was a lookup to the 'UserAvatar' field in the 'userprofiles' table